# How can I create a form in Postman?

Tags: postman, http-post

```json
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3",
    "key4":"value4",
    "key5":{
                "sub-key1":"value11", 
                "sub-key2":{
                                "skey1":"skvalue112",
                                "skey3":"skvalue114"
                            },
                "sub-key3":[
                        {"skey1":"skvalue112"},
                        {"skey2":"skvalue212"},
                        {"skey3":"skvalue312"},
                            .
                        {"skeyN":"skvalueN12"}
                            ]
            },                                  
"sub-key3":"value13",
"sub-key4":"value14"
}
```

I have the above JSON sample that I am using to post a request in Postman. I have all the other parts in the above JSON always remain the same, but I need to manually change the key-value pair inside the large bracket i.e. `[ ]`, and for "skey3" manually when I want to create a new request. Is there a way I can create a form in JSON that will only have the part I have to change?

For example, in form I can have:

```json
sub-key3: {"skey1":"skvalue112"},{"skey2":""skvalue212"},{"skey3":"skvalue312"},{"skeyN":"skvalueN12"}
skey3: skvalue114
```

When I have the form and value as above I get the JSON as above.